# SAP Hybris extend Backoffice - Spring bean overwrite

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to overwrite an backoffice class which has a bean, but it is in a web context.

In our project we have already an custom backoffice package, but there is no spring.xml. Also no other classes in that package have any beans.

To be more specific, I am trying to overwrite this class: `hybris/bin/ext-backoffice/backoffice/web/webroot/WEB-INF/classes/com/hybris/backoffice/widgets/searchadapters/conditions/products/FlexibleSearchUncategorizedConditionAdapter.class`.

Our backoffice extension looks like that:

```
├── backoffice <-- webroot
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── widgets
│   │       ├── projectbackofficeWidget
│   │       │   ├── definition.xml
│   │       │   ├── images
│   │       │   │   └── ...
│   │       │   ├── labels
│   │       │   │   └── ...
│   │       │   ├── projectbackofficewidget.scss
│   │       │   └── projectbackofficewidget.zul
│   │       └── actions
│   │           └── ...
│   ├── src
│   │   └── de
│   │       └── company
│   │           └── project
│   │               └── backoffice
│   │                   ├── b2bcommerce
│   │                   │   └── actions
│   │                   │       └── ...
│   │                   ├── editors
│   │                   │   └── ...
│   │                   ├── services
│   │                   │   └── ...
│   │                   └── widgets
│   │                       ├── ...
│   │                       └── searchadapters
│   │                           └── myFlexibleSearchUncategorizedConditionAdapter.java
│   └── testsrc
│       └── ...
├── build.xml
├── buildcallbacks.xml
├── extensioninfo.xml
├── extensioninfo.xsd
├── gensrc
│   └── ...
├── platformhome.properties
├── project.properties
├── resources
│   ├── backoffice
│   │   └── projectbackoffice_bof.jar
│   ├── beans.xsd
│   ├── cockpitng
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── items.xsd
│   ├── projectbackoffice
│   │   ├── projectbackoffice-testclasses.xml
│   │   └── projectbackoffice-webtestclasses.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-backoffice-labels
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── projectbackoffice-backoffice-spring.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-backoffice-widgets.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-beans.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-items.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice-spring.xml
│   ├── projectbackoffice.build.number
│   └── localization
│       └── ...
├── src
│   └── de
│       └── company
│           └── project
│               └── backoffice
│                   ├── projectbackofficeStandalone.java
│                   ├── constants
│                   │   └── projectbackofficeConstants.java
│                   └── jalo
│                       └── projectbackofficeManager.java
└── testsrc
    └── ...
```

I know there is an spring.xml, but it is not working with the classes in the webroot.
In all other web extensions, there are separated files for that.
How do I add an spring.xml so I can overwrite that OOTB bean? Or how can I use the existing spring.xml for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [customize](https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/use-ant-customize-command-in-hybris/) for that, but it seems there is a better solution that lets you append the backoffice web spring configs as mentioned [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12755934/how-to-override-bean-in-backoffice-web-context.html).